# Bootstrap button group hover colour change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap button group as a series of checkboxes.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons Checkbox section for working example.

When you hover over an unchecked button it changes to the same colour as a checked button.  If you then click on the button it does not change colour because it's already the same colour as the checked button.  So you then have to move the mouse away from the button to verify that you've actually clicked on it correctly.  Obviously a similar issue occurs when moving from a checked to an unchecked state.  I think this is slightly confusing for my users.  Is there any way to get a Bootstrap button to not change colour on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you've got a difference between `:hover` and `:active` buttons, you can see a slightly shadow on the button.

You can intensify this shadow using this code (which will work for every button, whatever their color) :

```
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Result :
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  From a visual point I wasn't too keen on the box shadow styling so I ended up combining your answer and mine and changed the background-color and border-color attributes on active buttons for that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around I'm currently overriding the hover colours on the page that I'm using the button group so that users can at least see that hovering is a different activity to having a button selected.

```
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #428bff;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}
```